# MySQL Error Code: 1030Got error -1 from storage engine; I've tried to delete data from my database

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-error-1030

I have a database including some tables, when I want to delete data from tables which includes an "Auto Increment" field, using this query:

```
delete from test.table1 ;
```

I got this error:

```
 Error Code: 1030Got error -1 from storage engine
```

Why this happens? What should I do?

Comment: Check the permissions and ownership of all the files. table1 engine is InnoDB? Which MySQL version do you use?

Comment: It's not permission problem, this error just occur when there is a an "auto increment" field in table1. The engine is "InnoDB" for all tables in database. version of the software is:5.2.25 CE.

Answer (score 7):

Try to change `innodb_force_recovery` value (in your `/etc/my.cnf`).

**Error -1** says NOTHING. Without your tables creation code (`SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name`) can not say where exactly problem is.

Comment: WARNING:  this is meant to recover your database. Good luck if you continue to use `innodb_force_recovery `.

Answer (score 3):

You also get this error, if your file system is full.

Comment: I want to know how to empty the file system. My error is #1030 - Got error -1 from storage engine. we just made OS clone from which server was installed.

Answer (score 1):

I just got this one and it was due to the fact that the new folder on the SSD drive where I wanted the new table to go was created under root and mysql runs under the mysql user. So 
cd to your data folder
chown mysql . 
and it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Go to /etc/my.cnf or /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Comment line innodb_force_recovery=1

Save the file and restart mysql

Answer (score 0):

try [repair](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-repair.html) table (ISAM engine)

if its innodb engine look at this link :

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/07/04/recovering-innodb-table-corruption/

Comment: I've checked my table, using this query, "CHECK TABLE `test`.`table1`;" the message text is "OK", so it means the table is not damaged, but can't even rename a field in this table :(

Answer (score 0):

I also met this error while deleting 2 rows from an Innodb table, only 2 particular rows can't be deleted. I Google the error, but can't find better solutions.

So i tried this:

1. Create a backup for my db (exporting db).
2. Re-Installing MySQL Server
3. Restoring my db (importing db).
4. Then there is no -1 engine error on deletion/update.

Success...

I think the error may occur due to invalid configuration of MySQL server with respect to storage engines.

Thank You....

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED!!** check your memory by `df -h`. also check inodes `df -i`. if its full, delete some files.

Answer (score 0):

I see no answer has been selected as the right answer.

I found that in our database config we had the *innodb_force_recovery* configured.
Once we disabled / commented it out, the queries ran as expected.

Comment: The top voted answer says the same thing. Do you want to add anything else to it?

Comment: The top voted answer says to change the value of innodb_force_recovery, but not to what the value should be or to remove / comment out the value in the config file.

Comment: Well it implies the same thing. If still not clear, there are other answers which says to specifically comment it. As I said above, your answer doesnt add anything to already posted answers.

Comment: @VivekKumar no, most voted answer doesn't say the same.It's not the same "change innodb_force_recovery" than "comment innodb_force_recovery or set to 0"

Answer (score 0):

Find the value of `innodb_force_recovery` at  `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`(for linux). if it is **0**, remove it or comment it out.

**Example**

```
innodb_force_recovery = 0
```

*change it to:*

```
#innodb_force_recovery = 0
```

**Reference:**

> InnoDB: innodb_force_recovery is on: we do not allow InnoDB: database
>   modifications by the user.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was solved by restarting my database (in my case Mariadb).

```
systemctl restart mariadb
```

Answer (score -1):

Just modify to

```
#innodb_force_recovery = 1
```

It works to me.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I solved it, I just had the same error:

1. Open Control Panel
2. Select Unistall Programs
3. Right click and select"Uninstall" on Microsoft Visual Basic Tools
4. Restart your PC

Comment: Can you explain how this fixes the problem? Doesn't this assume that OP is using Windows? What if you want to keep Microsoft Visual Basic Tools?