# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1030

Tags: mysql, error-handling, drupal-7

I am making a website with Drupal 7 on my localhost. Today I got the well-known error that my cache_rules was missing. I tried to restore it. That seemd to have worked, because I see the table in my database now. However, PHPMyadmin said after the query that the 'results came back empty'. Is this correct.

I used this code to restore it:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `XX_cache_rules` (`cid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Primary Key: Unique cache ID.', `data` longblob COMMENT 'A collection of data to cache.', `expire` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A Unix timestamp indicating when the cache entry should expire, or 0 for never.', `created` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A Unix timestamp indicating when the cache entry was created.', `serialized` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A flag to indicate whether content is serialized (1) or not (0).', PRIMARY KEY (`cid`), KEY `expire` (`expire`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Cache table for the rules engine to store configured items.';
```

It came from: https://www.drupal.org/node/2160645

But when I try to clear my caches now, I get a new error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1030 Got error -1 from storage engine: TRUNCATE {cache_rules} ; Array ( ) in cache_clear_all() (line 165 of C:\Users\Mariska\Sites\devdesktop\includes\cache.inc).
```

I have made a backup and reinstalled Dev Desktop. I replaced the Sites/DevDesktop folder with the one of my backup and placed the database.mysql in the MYSQL folder.

Then I got a cache_field error, restored that with a query and again the cache_rules error. Restored that in the same way as earlier. In both cases PHPMyadmin said that the 'results can back empty' after the query.

And then the same error 1030...

I finally figured it out. It was a storage problem afer all. It was my virus scanner that messed everything up, McAfee. I got a new one now, one that would not take so much space in the performance of my laptop. Let's see.

Thanks,
Mariska.

Comment: You should mark Claudiu's answer as the solution

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a mysql related issue.
This might help you though [MySQL Error Code: 1030Got error -1 from storage engine; I've tried to delete data from my database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067461/mysql-error-code-1030got-error-1-from-storage-engine-ive-tried-to-delete-dat)
In brief, your system disks are full or try a table/engine recovery.

Answer (score 1):

Same error, 64 bit MariaDB, Drupal, NOD32 antivirus. Solution: Disable the resident antivirus protection for MySQL folder.